# how does spring figure out that particular http request is mapped to which endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

How does spring figure out that a http request is mapped to which endpoint. I want to know about how does that abstraction layer works. Is it servlet filters play or dispatcher servlet?
I tried searching about the problem but all i get is big & vast concepts to read about

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses a dispatcher servlet as the front controller to handle incoming HTTP requests. When a request comes in, the dispatcher servlet uses a series of mechanisms to determine which endpoint should handle the request.

The primary mechanism used by Spring to map requests to endpoints is the use of annotations on controller methods. These annotations specify the URL path and HTTP method(s) that the method can handle. For example, the @RequestMapping annotation can be used to specify the URL path and HTTP method(s), like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    // retrieve and return the user with the given ID
}
```

In this example, the @RequestMapping annotation specifies that the getUser() method should handle GET requests to the /users/{id} path, where {id} is a path variable that will be passed as a parameter to the method.

Spring also supports other annotations for mapping requests, such as @GetMapping, @PostMapping, @PutMapping, @DeleteMapping, and others.

When a request comes in, the dispatcher servlet examines the request's URL path and HTTP method and looks for a controller method that has a matching mapping annotation. If a match is found, the method is called to handle the request.

In addition to mapping requests using annotations, Spring also supports other mechanisms for mapping requests, such as using HandlerMapping and HandlerAdapter classes and registering custom HandlerMapping and HandlerAdapter implementations.

Overall, Spring's abstraction layer for handling HTTP requests is built on top of the servlet API and uses a combination of annotations, configuration, and customizable components to provide a flexible and powerful framework for handling web requests.